# testing Facebook login with Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, facebook-login, koala

I'm logging in successfully with Facebook via Koala. I now want to test in Rspec my controller behavior, and for this I would like to set up a live environment where I register a user via Facebook.

The tutorials for how to create Facebook users are straigthforward vbut I have no idea how to match the user to a login event.

If anyone has a step-by-step, I'm afraid I'm out of my depth on this one. I have to keep coding but right now will leave the Facebook login implementation untested and as you all know that is really not good.